# Where should i save codeblocks projects?

Tags: c++, gcc, path, compiler-errors, codeblocks

so i downloaded codeblocks codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe

when i try to run main.cpp i get this error message:
Failed to open 'C:\Users\$imba\Documents\Codeblocks projects\test\main.cpp'.

this is a detailed summary of what i did prior to opening main.cpp

i selected the defaults all the way through the end. I created a seperate folder (called Codeblocks projects) in my documents to save the projects in.

now when i went to create a new folder, i selected console application, C++ and then i named my project test. i decided to create the project in the  Codeblocks projects folder that i created. the resulting filename comes out to be C:\Users\$imba\Documents\Codeblocks projects\test\test.cbd

i then selected 
GNU GCC Compiler, 
'Create Debug Configuration: Debug'
 output dir: bin\Debug\ 
 object dir.: obj\Debug\

i selected create Release configuration,: 'Release'
output dir.: bin\release\
objects output dir.: obj\ Release

Finish

when i double click on main.cpp is when i get the error message
Failed to open 'C:\Users\$imba\Documents\Codeblocks projects\test\main.cpp'.

please help, i need this program for my course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving it in a folder in `C:\`, like `C:\Cpp\`. Code::Blocks may be having problems with the space or the `$` in the file path.

Comment: I created a new folder in C:\ like you said and saved the file in it and it worked. thanks alot.   ps: $imba is my laptop's user name.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new folder CB-Project under my D: drive where I have codeblocks installed.

You may want to look in the directory that you have CB installed in first, you may also find this in program file (x86) or the codeblocks sub directory. Look for a file named that may have proj or project in it's name. If you don't find it you can just create a new folder. You will have to put the new folder name in the CB path so it will find it.